# простая задачка JS

Tags: javascript

Прога должна выявить сколько дней осталось до нового года! В чем заключается моя ошибка?

Выводит: `your inputs is not correct`

```js
var real;
var answer;
var days;
var year = 365;
var yMonth = prompt('Enter your month(with numbers)');
var yDay = prompt('Enter your day(with numbers)');

switch (yMonth) {
  case 1:
    {
      real = 31;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 2:
    {
      real = 59;
      days = 28;
      answer = (year - real + (days - yDay));
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 3:
    {
      real = 90;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 4:
    {
      real = 120;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 5:
    {
      real = 151;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 6:
    {
      real = 181;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 7:
    {
      real = 212;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 8:
    {
      real = 243;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 9:
    {
      real = 273;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 10:
    {
      real = 304;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 11:
    {
      real = 334;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 12:
    {
      real = 365;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  default:
    alert('your inputs is not correct');
}
```

Comment: то что юзер введет в `promt` всегда будет строкой, поетому нужно самому приводить результат к числу, например так : `+yMonth`

Comment: Високосные года вы как-то пропусти. И, если это не какое-то учебное задание, где условием является использование конструкции `switch`, то почему бы просто не вычислять разницу в днях между указанной датой и датой ближайшего от неё Нового года?

Comment: не, просто тренируюсь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В yMonth и yDay после ввода пользователя будут строки. В switch вы сравниваете их с числами, поэтому совпадений нет. Самый простой вариант преобразовать ввод пользователя к числу:

```
var yMonth=+prompt('Enter your month(with numbers)');
var yDay=+prompt('Enter your day(with numbers)');
```

```js
var real;
var answer;
var days;
var year=365;

var yMonth=+prompt('Enter your month(with numbers)');

var yDay=+prompt('Enter your day(with numbers)');

switch (yMonth) {
 case 1:{real=31;
     days=31;
     answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
     console.log(answer);
 break;
 }

 case 2:{real=59;
     days=28;
     answer=(year-real+(days-yDay));
     console.log(answer);
 break;}

 case 3:{real=90;
     days=31;
     answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
     console.log(answer);
 break;}

 case 4:{real=120;
     days=30;
     answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
     console.log(answer);
 break;}

 case 5:{real=151;
     days=31;
     answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
     console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 6:{real=181;
   days=30;
   answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
   console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 7:{real=212;
      days=31;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 8:{real=243;
      days=31;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 9:{real=273;
      days=30;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 10:{real=304;
      days=31;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 11:{real=334;
      days=30;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}

  case 12:{real=365;
      days=31;
      answer=year-real+(days-yDay);
      console.log(answer);
 break;}
 
 default:alert('your inputs is not correct');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вводимые юзером значения в `prompt` являются строками. Чтобы привести их к числовому типу, можно использовать, например, `parseInt()`:

```js
var real;
var answer;
var days;
var year = 365;

var yMonth = parseInt(prompt('Enter your month(with numbers)'));

var yDay = parseInt(prompt('Enter your day(with numbers)'));

switch (yMonth) {
  case 1:
    {
      real = 31;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 2:
    {
      real = 59;
      days = 28;
      answer = (year - real + (days - yDay));
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 3:
    {
      real = 90;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 4:
    {
      real = 120;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 5:
    {
      real = 151;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 6:
    {
      real = 181;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 7:
    {
      real = 212;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 8:
    {
      real = 243;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 9:
    {
      real = 273;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 10:
    {
      real = 304;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 11:
    {
      real = 334;
      days = 30;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  case 12:
    {
      real = 365;
      days = 31;
      answer = year - real + (days - yDay);
      console.log(answer);
      break;
    }

  default:
    alert('your inputs is not correct');

}
```